# Alphabetize Grid with... JS? CSS?

Tags: javascript, sorting, grid, alphabetical-sort

I have a grid I'd like to keep in alphabetical order without manually intervening. I.e. that I can continue adding to without re-alphabetizing every time. The grid itself is very simple, just 3 columns with hyperlinks in each 'gridObject'. I'd like the grid to simply be sorted by the link text (or id?) when the page loads, without clicking anything (a document.ready function?).

```
<style>
    #gridContainer{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        background-color:#420666;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .gridObject{
        min-width: 200px;
        background-color:#666420;
        margin:15px;
        padding:10px;
        color:#fff;
    }
</style>

<div id="gridContainer">
    <div class="gridObject" id="qLink"><a href="">qLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="wLink"><a href="">wLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="eLink"><a href="">eLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="rLink"><a href="">rLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="tLink"><a href="">tLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="yLink"><a href="">yLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="uLink"><a href="">uLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="uLink"><a href="">iLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="oLink"><a href="">oLink</a></div>
    <div class="gridObject" id="pLink"><a href="">pLink</a></div>
</div>
```

I was searching for various JS methods to sort arrays, etc, but haven't found anything yet for html tables/grids except making sortable columns. I'm very new to all this so this is very much a learning exercise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking fo a non-js solution?

Comment: Whatever is most effective. I just don't know js well enough to figure it out on my own but I'd love to learn

Comment: Super helpful. Note that id of 3rd div from bottom should be "iLink".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a sortGrid() function to sort all the element inside the gridObject class to get sorted alphabetically  using id's

```
// Function based on id of element
function sortGrid(){
    const gridObject = document.querySelectorAll('.gridObject')
    let array = [];
    gridObject.forEach(grid =>  array.push(grid.getAttribute("id")))
    array.sort()
    array.forEach((item, index) => array[index] = document.querySelector("#"+item))
    const gridContainer = document.querySelector('#gridContainer');
    gridContainer.innerHTML = ""
    array.forEach(grid => gridContainer.innerHTML += grid.outerHTML)
}

 sortGrid()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote a function that might help!

```js
  function sortMyElements() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("gridContainer");

    var links = Array.from(parent.children);

    parent.innerHTML = "";

    var sortedLinks = links.sort(
      (first, second) =>
        first.getAttribute("id").charCodeAt(0) - second.getAttribute("id").charCodeAt(0) //sorting by character code
    );

    sortedLinks.forEach((link) => parent.appendChild(link));
  }
```

Comment: Hi @FMoosavi, this one also worked perfectly but I can only accept one as the solution. Thanks for your help!